# PlayFramework 2.4, Actor injection issue: There is no started application

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, actor

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570547/calling-a-service-on-startup-in-a-play-application) has been asked, but I didn't find it very helpful. I am injecting `MyRepository` into `MyActor`. On startup, I get the following exception:

```
[error] - akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy - Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at infrastructure.repository.MyRepository.<init>(MyRepository.scala:13)
  at infrastructure.repository.MyRepository.class(MyRepository.scala:13)
  while locating infrastructure.repository.MyRepository
    for parameter 0 at service.command.MyActor.<init>(MyActor.scala:38)
  at service.command.MyActor.class(MyActor.scala:38)
  while locating service.command.MyActor

1 error
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
        at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:172) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:605) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:460) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:482) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234) [akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
.... [same thing]
```

I have followed the instructions and I have a module like

```
class InjectionModule extends AbstractModule with AkkaGuiceSupport {
  def configure = {
    bindActor[MyActor]("my-actor")
  }
}
```

This is the code for MyRepository:

```
@Singleton
class MyRepository @Inject()(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) extends Repository {

  // init db connection
  override val collection = getCollection(reactiveMongoApi, "card")

  def getById(id: CardId) = get(Json.obj(Entity.JSON_KEY_ID -> id.toString))

  // .. other similar methods
}


abstract class Repository {
  val collection: JSONCollection

  val dbName = current.configuration.getString("mongodb.database.name").getOrElse("")

  protected def getCollection(reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi, name: String) =
    reactiveMongoApi.connection.db(dbName, FailoverStrategy(initialDelay = 1.second, retries = 20)).collection[JSONCollection](name)

  protected def get(query: JsObject): Future[Either[String, Option[A]]] = {
    collection.find(query).one[A].map {
      case Some(a) => Right(Some(a))
      case None => Right(None)
    }.recover { case t => Left(t.getMessage) }
  }

  // ... similar methods
}
```

And this is the 'opening line' for MyActor:

```
@Singleton
class MyActor @Inject()(cardViewRepository: CardViewRepository) extends Actor {
  //.. actor methods
}
```

What's interesting is that it used to work and all of a sudden it's throwing this exception. Maybe because I upgraded from 2.4.3 to 2.4.6?

Comment: Can you show your `MyRepository` code? The problem seems to be there in the constructor. Maybe you are using some Play component there that needs to be injected also (ex: `Configuration`, `Play.application()`, etc)?

Comment: @Salem thanks for your comment. Code added.

Comment: It is difficult to say for sure when imports and line numbers aren't available. Could it be this line, where you access the current app?

`val dbName = current.configuration.getString("mongodb.database.name").getOrElse("")`

Comment: @ticofab Probably the problem is with `current` as stated above. Try to inject `Configuration` in your `MyRepository` class and use in instead of `current.configuration`. If you really need the application object I think you can inject it instead...

Comment: Thanks both, the problem seemed to be indeed in the missing "current". I injected the configuration as suggested by Salem and the problem seems to be solved. Someone please post an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: @ticofab You can add an answer for yourself and accept it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Salem in the comments was right: "Probably the problem is with current as stated above. Try to inject Configuration in your MyRepository class and use in instead of current.configuration. If you really need the application object I think you can inject it instead... "
I needed to inject the Configuration in MyRepository.